# How to verify HTTP::Response data is really complete 100% downloaded

Tags: perl, http-headers, httpresponse, perl-module

```
$url = "http://203.155.220.231/radar/pics/radarh.jpg";

use LWP::UserAgent; 
$ua         = new LWP::UserAgent;   
$request    = new HTTP::Request;
$request->method('GET');
$request->url($url);
$response   = $ua->request($request);   

if ( $response->is_error or 
     $response->header('Content-Type')   ne 'image/jpeg' or 
     $response->header('Content-Length') ne length($response->content)
   )
{
    print $response->status_line . "\n";
    print $response->header('Content-Length') . "\n";
    print length($response->content) . "\n";
    die "$!";
}
```

By checking $response->header('Content-Length') compare with length($response->content) is easiest way to verify data is really complete 100% downloaded ?

Comment: Then, what is your problem?

Comment: Sometime jpeg broken or lost connection on slow internet.  Is there a way to check that we receive data correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the response from the server.
If the server sends a Content-Length header then you could use this to verify the length. But if the server uses chunked Transfer-Encoding or simply closes the connection at the end of the response you cannot use this information. Such kind of responses are typical for dynamically generated content. And as far as I can see there are no information in these cases which let you determine if the download was complete or not.

Comment: Re "*And as far as I can see there are no information [if the server uses chunked Transfer-Encoding] which let you determine if the download was complete or not*", What? The entire reason chunked is used is to provide that information!!!

Comment: @ikegami: in theory chunked encoding provides this information. But from looking at HTTP::Methods::read_entity_body it looks for me that  it is not propagated to the user if the final chunk was received or if the server closed the connection before the final chunk was received. Which means that you cannot verify if the download was complete.

Answer (score 0):

To check download complete, You should get total size of file before download. Then You can check download complete easily.

Comment: And how do you get the size of the file before download?

Comment: Easy! If you don't have a complete header, you didn't get the entire response. If the responses uses a Content-Length header, you have the size of the response in advance. If the server uses a chunked response, you have the size of the next check in advance. If the server uses neither, party like it's 1999. It's possible to detect shortened responses. The question is Net::HTTP/LWP::Protocol::http detect thems. (It definitely does in the case of network failure, but I'm not sure what happens if the sockets gets closed prematurely (e.g. if the web server segfaults).)

Comment: Checking for `$response->header('X-Died')` can be helpful.